# prevent script from being executed on ssh session start

Tags: linux, ubuntu

To connect to my server using ssh, I've been using the `fig ssh`command from the fig.io terminal extension.

The problem is now each time I connect to this server, using fig or using the ssh command directly, the session opens and launch the `curl -fSsL https://fig.io/install-headless.sh | bash; exec $SHELL` command.

I have tried to clean the ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, but I can't seems to prevent this behaviour.

Any idea what makes it so that is command is executed on the start of my ssh session? Where should I look?

Comment: Are there any unusual lines inside `~/.ssh/config`? I ask because this page says it adds to your SSH config file. https://fig.io/user-manual/autocomplete/ssh

Comment: Same issue for me, I installed it on a remote server but I want to uninstall it and can't remove it...
I tried to remove it with the command `fig uninstall` but it keep reinstalled after each SSH login ...

Comment: @NickODell : There was something indeed in the `.ssh/config` file. I remove it all, `sudo reboot` then try to open a new ssh session without fig (using the classic `ssh -l ... `command) : problem persist

Comment: @iStornZ : I've been using fig for more than a year, mainly to simply the ssh connect to all my servers. This new headless fig installation on server is new, and it's really annoying!

Comment: @NickODell : The problem was in the `~/.ssh/config` of my LOCAL machine. Fig had added a script that would execute each time i connect to a host in ssh, using `fig ssh` or classic `ssh`. l clean the `~/.ssh/config` on my machine and Voila! since you came up with that, If you want to submit the answer, I'll validate it!

Comment: @FlorianBurel Do you mind giving me a few more details to make this answer useful for future searchers? 1) What were the lines you removed from `~/.ssh/config`? You can edit my answer to add them. 2) Did you have to remove lines from the server's `~/.ssh/config` too, or just your local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~/.ssh/config` file, on your local computer, can contain a command that gets run before connecting to the remote host. You should check there.

Edit by Florian:
Fig indeed adds a couple of line in your local `~/.ssh/config`. It does it well by also adding comment lines above to let you know what has been added, so it's fairly easy to undo. Removing/commenting the lines stops the unwanted behaviour.
Thank you for pointing me in this direction I was going mad!